# How to access element of JSON using Qt

Tags: c++, json, qt, youtube-api, qjsonobject

I have this Json object and I want to access the "duration" and show it on console using Qt :

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"cbz3lIQ2N25AfwNr-BdxUVxJ_QY/brZ0pmrmXldPPKpGPRM-8I4dDFQ\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"cbz3lIQ2N25AfwNr-BdxUVxJ_QY/PkTW6UN9MH0O2kDApjC3penIiKs\"",
   "id": "WkC18w6Ys7Y",
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT58M21S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "hd",
    "caption": "false",
    "licensedContent": true,
    "projection": "rectangular"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

And my Qt code is this :

```
{
    QJsonDocument jsonResponse = QJsonDocument::fromJson(message);
    results = jsonResponse.object();

    QJsonValue v1 = results.value("items");

    qDebug() << "v1 = " << v1;

    QJsonValue v2 = v1.toObject().value("contentDetails");

    qDebug() <<"v2 = " << v2;

    QString v3 = v2.toObject().value("duration").toString();

    qDebug() << "v3 = " << v3;
}
```

However my output is :

v1 =  QJsonValue(array, QJsonArray([{"contentDetails":{"caption":"false","definition":"hd","dimension":"2d","duration":"PT58M21S","licensedContent":true,"projection":"rectangular"},"etag":"\"cbz3lIQ2N25AfwNr-BdxUVxJ_QY/PkTW6UN9MH0O2kDApjC3penIiKs\"","id":"WkC18w6Ys7Y","kind":"youtube#video"}]))

v2 =  QJsonValue(undefined)

v3 =  ""

So v1 is fine but v2 becomes undefined.What am I doing wrong and how can I access the "duration" item correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct answer as follows:

```
// Read the file which has the JSON object.
QFile file("jsonString.json");
if(!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly)){
    qDebug()<< "Error, Cannot open the file.";
    return false;
}

QJsonDocument jsonDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(file.readAll());
qDebug()<< jsonDoc.object().value("items").toArray()[0].toObject().value("contentDetails").toObject().value("duration").toString();
```

The result:
`PT58M21S`

Answer (score 1):

`items` is a list, so calling [toObject()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonvalue.html#toObject) on it just returns the default value. According to the documentation:

> Converts the value to an object and returns it.
>
> If type() is not Object, the defaultValue will be returned.

You need to be calling [toArray()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonvalue.html#toArray) on it, which will convert it to a [QJsonArray](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonarray.html#QJsonArray). From there you can take the first item from the array using a variety of methods, or iterate over the array if that makes more sense for your schema.